# Request Parameters with php 7.4 and magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2.4, array, http-request, request, php-7.4

After updating from 2.3.5p2 to 2.4.1 and from php 7.1 to php 7.4 I have strange trouble with request parameters.

I see, that there are parameters set, when I var_dump

```
$parameters=$this->request->getParams();

var_dump($parameters);
```

Output:

```
array(5) { ["key"]=> string(64) "4e10c465f6988a7fjdueia57dbac2407f7990206d27eb47d531c5a94311ca51fd" ["namespace"]=> string(10) "importgrid" ["filters"]=> array(1) { ["placeholder"]=> string(4) "true" } ["paging"]=> array(2) { ["pageSize"]=> string(2) "20" ["current"]=> string(1) "1" } ["isAjax"]=> string(4) "true" }
```

I can also access `$parameters["key"];` but every other value gives me an error:

`var_dump($parameters["paging"])`;

`Notice: Undefined index: paging in .....`

Its like those array keys dont exist, even they show up in the dump $parameters...
Any ideas, what is happening here? Have I missed something big in php-arrays from 7.1 to 7.4?

Comment: This makes no sense, must be something else that is wrong, do u have the full code including the request?

Comment: Here is the compolete DataProvider:
https://pastebin.com/AJYPKjqt

Comment: I try to access paging (pagesize) and paging(current), sorting (field) and sorting (direction)...
line 242-243 and 292 - 293

Comment: what do you get if you var_dump($this->request->getParam('sorting')) on line 243 ?

Comment: I just get NULL

Comment: without dumping I get this notice:
`Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /app/vendor/myvendor/koleso/Ui/DataProvider/KolesoProvider.php on line 242`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I came back to answer the question myself.

The problem is, that you can't declare an null value to a variable with php 7.4.
You can handle it by setting a condition:

```
if (isset($this->request->getParam('sorting')['field'])) {
  $field=$this->request->getParam('sorting')['field'];
}
else {
  $field="id";
}
```

Same goes for direction, pagesize and current page.